# Relative control positioning working incorrectly in Winforms MDI child with scrollbars, VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms, mdi

I have a VB.NET app with an MDI parent window which has Autoscroll, and an MDI child window which is occasionally larger than its parent. So long as the scrollbars are all the way to the top and left, or the MDI child is not larger than the parent, setting relative control positions in code seems to work - i.e.:

```
Control1.Left = Control2.Right + 10
Control1.Top = Control2.Top
```

When the MDI child is larger than its parent, and scrolled, the relative positioning appears to be off by exactly the amount scrolled. In the above example, Control2 should end up at the same Y as Control 1, 10 pixels to the right, but if the MDI parent window has scrollbars and has been scrolled 25 pixels right and 12 pixels down, then Control2 ends up 12 pixels below and 35 pixels to the right.

How do I properly set the top/left/location values of controls on an MDI child form in such a way that they are actually relative to the parent control and not the viewport?

Comment: I'd have to do some testing to work out the exact relationship but I'm guessing that you would have to take the `AutoScrollOffset` of something into account.  Not sure whether it would be that of `Control2` or of the MDI child form containing it.  A bit of experimentation should reveal the correct solution but I'm guessing something like `Control1.Top = Control2.Top + Control2.AutoScrollOffset.Y`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney found it in AutoScrollPosition rather than Offset, but climbing the Parent tree and hunting for that setting was the key, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the Getter for these properties returns an absolute position relative to the top-left corner of the form, while the Setter operates relative to the viewport instead, requiring the values to be offset in the instance that those geometries are not identical.

Climbing the `Control.Parent` hierarchy I eventually found a Form object that had a non-zero `AutoScrollPosition`. I was able to modify the statements setting the new controls' position using the `AutoScrollPosition.X` and `.Y` as appropriate, which corrected for the offset.